# Can't Delete Folder, Hard Drive Issue - ci_free_count is not valid

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, filevault

Running the latest MacBook Pro from Fall 2019. 2 TB internal SSD. Was doing a build and the power cut out.  Restarted the computer and found a folder that I could not delete. Tried all the tricks:

1. `sudo rm rf *` - did not work said directory not empty
2. `ls -la` what files are in here, no files are in there
3. Ok, let's just `rm -rf *` in this folder - weird a bunch of files show up related to my build, but rm gives me the a bunch of errors e.g., `rm: Filename.ext: No such file or directory`
4. Alright, reboot into recovery mode and try the same thing - same issue
5. OK, run First Aid - ah we got a problem (see pic below)
6. Run First Aid again, problem not going away
7. Run First Aid one more time, still getting the same error
8. Fine, mount the volume and then fsck_apfs it using terminal - same error
9. OK, let's turn off FileVault and try everything all over again - no luck

I've escalated to as high as I think. Anyone want to take a stab at this? Last step for me is to format the disk but that's super annoying.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should try rm -Rf  *  from the directory you want to remove.

Comment: like @jmh said, try `sudo rm -fr nameOfFolder/`. It should be blown away.

Comment: No luck, getting the error "Directory not empty", attached a screenshot

Comment: Try doing ```sudo chmod 777 -R foldername``` then ```sudo rm -rf foldername```.

Comment: Or just `sudo rm -rf foldername`

Comment: No dice with those :(